# PyQt5. Считать значения столбца или строки таблицы без цикла

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, gui, qtablewidget

Можно ли считать значения всего столбца или строки таблицы без перебора их по циклу?

Сейчас делаю с перебором по циклу:

```
def get_column_data(self, column):
    data = []
    for i in range(self.ui.tableWidget.rowCount()):
        data.append(self.ui.tableWidget.item(i, column).text())
    return data
```

Интересует можно ли сделать это более элегантно без цикла?

Answer (score 3):

Сейчас вы делаете:

```
tableWidget = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
tableWidget
[[1, 2, 3], 
 [4, 5, 6], 
 [7, 8, 9]]

def get_column_data(column):
    data = []
    for row in tableWidget:
        data.append(str(row[column]))
    return data

get_column_data(1)
['2', '5', '8']
```

Одной строкой будет так:

```
data = [ str(row[1])   for row in tableWidget]
data
['2', '5', '8']
```

Все работает !!!

```
from PyQt5 import Qt

class TableExample(Qt.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.table      = Qt.QTableWidget(3, 3)
        self.fillButton = Qt.QPushButton("Заполнить ячейки (выделенные ячейки)", self)
        self.fillButton.clicked.connect(self.onFill)

        layout = Qt.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.table)
        layout.addWidget(self.fillButton)

    def onFill(self):
        for i, index in enumerate(self.table.selectedIndexes()):
            item = Qt.QTableWidgetItem()
            item.setText(str(i))
            self.table.setItem(index.row(), index.column(), item)

        self.get_column_data(1)           # будем выбирать столбец с индексом `1`

    def get_column_data(self, column):
#        data = []
#        for i in range(self.table.rowCount()):
#            data.append(self.table.item(i, column).text())
#        print("data ->", data)    

        data = [ self.table.item(row, column).text()
                  for row in range(self.table.rowCount())
                  if self.table.item(row, column) is not None ]

        print("data->", data)
        return data            


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Qt.QApplication([])
    w = TableExample()
    w.show()
    app.exec()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ваша идея понятна, но так видимо не работает с tableWidget из PyQt

Comment: @Duncan Посмотрите пример, все работает.

Comment: Теперь разобрался. Сначала пытался проделать этот фокус буквально, без использования **rowCount()** и **item(row, column).text()**. Но во втором случае получается буквальное повторение того, что я делал изначально, но с использованием генератора. Мой вопрос заключался в следующем - может быть есть какое-то свойство для чтения столбца из таблицы? Что бы не надо было перебирать столбцы по циклу или генератором.

Comment: @Duncan ,  нет свойства для чтения столбца из таблицы.