# Как подставить данные из таблицы Pyqt5 в таблицу шаблон в word?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, ms-word, docxtpl

Я создал таблицу в qt designer и вывожу данные с нее в массив. Но, как сделать так чтоб данные автоматические вставлялись в уже готовый документ word в определенные ячейки в таблице?

pattern_gui.py

```
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        if not MainWindow.objectName():
            MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(640, 475)
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(u"gridLayout")
        self.tabWidget = QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName(u"tabWidget")
        self.tab = QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName(u"tab")
        self.gridLayout_5 = QGridLayout(self.tab)
        self.gridLayout_5.setObjectName(u"gridLayout_5")
        self.gridLayout_3 = QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout_3.setObjectName(u"gridLayout_3")
        self.pushButton_2 = QPushButton(self.tab)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName(u"pushButton_2")

        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.pushButton_2, 5, 0, 1, 1)

        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit(self.tab)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName(u"lineEdit")

        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 1, 0, 1, 1)

        self.label_2 = QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_2.setObjectName(u"label_2")

        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_2, 2, 0, 1, 1)

        self.label = QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label.setObjectName(u"label")

        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.lineEdit_2 = QLineEdit(self.tab)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName(u"lineEdit_2")

        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.lineEdit_2, 3, 0, 1, 1)

        self.pushButton = QPushButton(self.tab)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(u"pushButton")

        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.pushButton, 4, 0, 1, 1)

        self.verticalSpacer = QSpacerItem(20, 40, QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Expanding)

        self.gridLayout_3.addItem(self.verticalSpacer, 6, 0, 1, 1)


        self.gridLayout_5.addLayout(self.gridLayout_3, 0, 2, 1, 1)

        self.gridLayout_4 = QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout_4.setObjectName(u"gridLayout_4")
        self.lineEdit_3 = QLineEdit(self.tab)
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName(u"lineEdit_3")

        self.gridLayout_4.addWidget(self.lineEdit_3, 1, 0, 1, 1)

        self.label_4 = QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_4.setObjectName(u"label_4")

        self.gridLayout_4.addWidget(self.label_4, 2, 0, 1, 1)

        self.lineEdit_4 = QLineEdit(self.tab)
        self.lineEdit_4.setObjectName(u"lineEdit_4")

        self.gridLayout_4.addWidget(self.lineEdit_4, 3, 0, 1, 1)

        self.lineEdit_5 = QLineEdit(self.tab)
        self.lineEdit_5.setObjectName(u"lineEdit_5")

        self.gridLayout_4.addWidget(self.lineEdit_5, 5, 0, 1, 1)

        self.label_5 = QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_5.setObjectName(u"label_5")

        self.gridLayout_4.addWidget(self.label_5, 4, 0, 1, 1)

        self.label_6 = QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_6.setObjectName(u"label_6")

        self.gridLayout_4.addWidget(self.label_6, 6, 0, 1, 1)

        self.label_3 = QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_3.setObjectName(u"label_3")

        self.gridLayout_4.addWidget(self.label_3, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.lineEdit_6 = QLineEdit(self.tab)
        self.lineEdit_6.setObjectName(u"lineEdit_6")

        self.gridLayout_4.addWidget(self.lineEdit_6, 7, 0, 1, 1)

        self.label_7 = QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_7.setObjectName(u"label_7")

        self.gridLayout_4.addWidget(self.label_7, 8, 0, 1, 1)

        self.lineEdit_7 = QLineEdit(self.tab)
        self.lineEdit_7.setObjectName(u"lineEdit_7")

        self.gridLayout_4.addWidget(self.lineEdit_7, 9, 0, 1, 1)


        self.gridLayout_5.addLayout(self.gridLayout_4, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.horizontalSpacer = QSpacerItem(40, 20, QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Minimum)

        self.gridLayout_5.addItem(self.horizontalSpacer, 0, 1, 1, 1)

        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.tab_2 = QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName(u"tab_2")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QGridLayout(self.tab_2)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName(u"gridLayout_2")
        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget(self.tab_2)
        if (self.tableWidget.columnCount() < 10):
            self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(10)
        __qtablewidgetitem = QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, __qtablewidgetitem)
        __qtablewidgetitem1 = QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, __qtablewidgetitem1)
        __qtablewidgetitem2 = QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, __qtablewidgetitem2)
        __qtablewidgetitem3 = QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, __qtablewidgetitem3)
        __qtablewidgetitem4 = QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(4, __qtablewidgetitem4)
        __qtablewidgetitem5 = QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(5, __qtablewidgetitem5)
        __qtablewidgetitem6 = QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(6, __qtablewidgetitem6)
        __qtablewidgetitem7 = QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(7, __qtablewidgetitem7)
        __qtablewidgetitem8 = QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(8, __qtablewidgetitem8)
        __qtablewidgetitem9 = QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(9, __qtablewidgetitem9)
        if (self.tableWidget.rowCount() < 10):
            self.tableWidget.setRowCount(10)
        __qtablewidgetitem10 = QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, __qtablewidgetitem10)
        __qtablewidgetitem11 = QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(1, __qtablewidgetitem11)
        __qtablewidgetitem12 = QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(2, __qtablewidgetitem12)
        __qtablewidgetitem13 = QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(3, __qtablewidgetitem13)
        __qtablewidgetitem14 = QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(4, __qtablewidgetitem14)
        __qtablewidgetitem15 = QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(5, __qtablewidgetitem15)
        __qtablewidgetitem16 = QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(6, __qtablewidgetitem16)
        __qtablewidgetitem17 = QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(7, __qtablewidgetitem17)
        __qtablewidgetitem18 = QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(8, __qtablewidgetitem18)
        __qtablewidgetitem19 = QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(9, __qtablewidgetitem19)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName(u"tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(125)

        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.tableWidget, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        self.tab_3 = QWidget()
        self.tab_3.setObjectName(u"tab_3")
        self.gridLayout_6 = QGridLayout(self.tab_3)
        self.gridLayout_6.setObjectName(u"gridLayout_6")
        self.widget = QWidget(self.tab_3)
        self.widget.setObjectName(u"widget")

        self.gridLayout_6.addWidget(self.widget, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_3, "")

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tabWidget, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setObjectName(u"menubar")
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 640, 21))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(u"statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)

        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(1)


        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"MainWindow", None))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u0417\u0430\u0433\u0440\u0443\u0437\u0438\u0442\u044c \u0434\u0430\u043d\u043d\u044b\u0435 \u0432 \u0448\u0430\u0431\u043b\u043e\u043d", None))
        self.label_2.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u0414\u0438\u0440\u0435\u043a\u0442\u043e\u0440\u0438\u044f \u0441\u043e\u0445\u0440\u0430\u043d\u0435\u043d\u0438\u044f:", None))
        self.label.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u0418\u043c\u044f \u0444\u0430\u0439\u043b\u0430:", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u0421\u043e\u0445\u0440\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0442\u044c", None))
        self.label_4.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u0414\u0430\u0442\u0430:", None))
        self.label_5.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u0417\u0430\u044f\u0432\u043a\u0430/\u0434\u0430\u0442\u0430 \u043f\u043e\u043b\u0443\u0447\u0435\u043d\u0438\u044f \u043e\u0431\u0440\u0430\u0437\u0446\u043e\u0432", None))
        self.label_6.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u041e\u0431\u044c\u0435\u043a\u0442 \u0438\u0441\u043f\u044b\u0442\u0430\u043d\u0438\u044f:", None))
        self.label_3.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u041d\u043e\u043c\u0435\u0440 \u043f\u0440\u043e\u0442\u043e\u043a\u043e\u043b\u0430:", None))
        self.label_7.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u041c\u0430\u0440\u043a\u0438\u0440\u043e\u0432\u043a\u0430:", None))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u041e\u0441\u043d\u043e\u0432\u043d\u044b\u0435 \u0434\u0430\u043d\u043d\u044b\u0435", None))
        ___qtablewidgetitem = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        ___qtablewidgetitem.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u0414\u0430\u0442\u0430", None));
        ___qtablewidgetitem1 = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        ___qtablewidgetitem1.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u041e\u0431\u0449\u0435\u0435 \u0432\u0440\u0435\u043c\u044f, \u0447\u0430\u0441", None));
        ___qtablewidgetitem2 = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        ___qtablewidgetitem2.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u" pH,\n"
"\u0435\u0434. pH\n"
"", None));
        ___qtablewidgetitem3 = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
        ___qtablewidgetitem3.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u043f\u043e\u0433\u0440\u0435\u0448\u043d\u043e\u0441\u0442\u044c \u00b1\u0394,\n"
"\u0435\u0434. pH \n"
"", None));
        ___qtablewidgetitem4 = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(4)
        ___qtablewidgetitem4.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u" \u0421(Fe \u043e\u0431\u0449.),\n"
"\u043c\u0433/\u0434\u043c3\n"
"", None));
        ___qtablewidgetitem5 = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(5)
        ___qtablewidgetitem5.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u043f\u043e\u0433\u0440\u0435\u0448\u043d\u043e\u0441\u0442\u044c \u00b1\u0394,\n"
" \u043c\u0433/\u0434\u043c3\n"
"", None));
        ___qtablewidgetitem6 = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(6)
        ___qtablewidgetitem6.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u0421(\u0421\u041e2),\n"
"\u043c\u0433/\u0434\u043c3\n"
"", None));
        ___qtablewidgetitem7 = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(7)
        ___qtablewidgetitem7.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u043f\u043e\u0433\u0440\u0435\u0448\u043d\u043e\u0441\u0442\u044c \u00b1\u0394,\n"
"\u043c\u0433/\u0434\u043c3 \n"
"", None));
        ___qtablewidgetitem8 = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(9)
        ___qtablewidgetitem8.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u043f\u043e\u0433\u0440\u0435\u0448\u043d\u043e\u0441\u0442\u044c \u00b1\u0394,", None));
        ___qtablewidgetitem9 = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        ___qtablewidgetitem9.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"1", None));
        ___qtablewidgetitem10 = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(1)
        ___qtablewidgetitem10.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"2", None));
        ___qtablewidgetitem11 = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(2)
        ___qtablewidgetitem11.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"3", None));
        ___qtablewidgetitem12 = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(3)
        ___qtablewidgetitem12.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"4", None));
        ___qtablewidgetitem13 = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(4)
        ___qtablewidgetitem13.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"5", None));
        ___qtablewidgetitem14 = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(5)
        ___qtablewidgetitem14.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"6", None));
        ___qtablewidgetitem15 = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(6)
        ___qtablewidgetitem15.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"7", None));
        ___qtablewidgetitem16 = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(7)
        ___qtablewidgetitem16.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"8", None));
        ___qtablewidgetitem17 = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(8)
        ___qtablewidgetitem17.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"9", None));
        ___qtablewidgetitem18 = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(9)
        ___qtablewidgetitem18.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"10", None));
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u0422\u0430\u0431\u043b\u0438\u0446\u0430", None))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_3), QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u0413\u0440\u0430\u0444\u0438\u043a", None))
    # retranslateUi
```

Имеющиеся логика:

pattern_log.py

```
# Импорт библиотек
import os
import sys
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from pattern_gui import Ui_MainWindow
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate
import docx
# Новый экземпляр QApplication
app = QApplication(sys.argv)

Window = QMainWindow()
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(Window)
Window.setFixedSize(640, 480)
Window.show()

def buttonLoader():
    rows = ui.tableWidget.rowCount()
    cols = ui.tableWidget.columnCount()
    data = []
    for row in range(rows):
        tmp = []
        for col in range(cols):
            try:
                tmp.append(ui.tableWidget.item(row, col).text())
            except:
                tmp.append('')
        data.append(tmp)

    data_for_word = []
    # for i in data: print(i)

    for i in data:
        if i[0] != '':
            data_for_word.append(i)

            # добавляем таблицу
        doc = docx.Document()
        table = doc.add_table(rows=len(data_for_word), cols=3)
        # применяем стиль для таблицы
        table.style = 'Table Grid'

        # заполняем таблицу данными
        for row in range(len(data_for_word)):
            for col in range(3):
                print(str(data_for_word[row][col]))
                # получаем ячейку таблицы
                cell = table.cell(row, col)
                # записываем в ячейку данные
                cell.text = str(data_for_word[row][col])

        doc.save('table.docx')

ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(buttonLoader)

# Закрытие программы
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Если кто знает то покажите на моем коде или на своем примере как сделать так как я писал выше. Таблица вот такого вида:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: Пример данных для записи в шаблон]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Наверное надо начать с чего-то вроде `QAxObject *wordApp = new QAxObject("Word.Application");`

Comment: Не совсем понял откуда этот отрывок кода. Можете показать на примере или чем то подобным?

Comment: Думаю, вам сначала надо почитать докуменацию Miscrosoft про COM-интерфейс(ActiveX) к word. В Qt же есть пакет облегчающий программирование COM - `Active Qt`. `QAxObject` оттуда

Comment: Вот например https://evileg.com/en/forum/topic/596

Comment: Что у вас в переменной data? Приведите пример данных в самом вопросе. У вас должно получиться столько документов, сколько элементов в списке data, или все данные должны попасть в один документ?

Comment: P.S. лучше не спамить однотипными вопросами (фактически дублировать один и тот же вопрос несколько раз). Если задавать постоянно низкокачественные вопросы, то можно получить автоматическую блокировку возможности задавать вопросы. Лучше задайте вопрос один раз, и его дополняйте. При каждом редактировании вопрос поднимается на главной странице сайта.

Comment: В переменной data хранятся данные со всех столбцев и строк. Но что бы вставить эти данные шаблон как сдесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/900232/pyqt5-%D0%A1%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B1%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0 необходимо получать данные только по каждому столбцу, а после как по шаблону вставлять.

Comment: Чтобы я смог ответить на ваш вопрос, мне нужно видеть конкретные данные из data, т.к. я не планирую собирать полную копию вашего приложения - для ответа на вопрос это не нужно. Просто сделайте print(data) перед вторым циклом, и добавьте в вопрос то что выведется.

Comment: Хорошо. Но учтите что данных всегда разное количество может быть одна строчка, а может и 2,3,4 и тд.

Comment: Добавил, пример данных.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если есть шаблон, который нужно заполнить, загружайте его через `DocxTemplate()` и потом заполняйте, а не создавайте новый пустой документ через `docx.Document()`.

Для вывода в шаблон из вопроса нужно заполнить список `data_for_word` словарями, каждый словарь — это строка в таблице, в каждом из этих словарей ключ соответствует названию ячейки (то что в шаблоне идет после точки), значения — значение в этой ячейке.

Для шаблона из вопроса заполнение будет выглядеть так:

```
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate

...


data_for_word = []

for item in data:
    data_for_word.append({
        "data": item[0],
        "time": item[1],
        "ph": item[2],
        "ph2": item[3],
        "fe": item[4],
        "pm": item[5],
        "co2": item[6],
        "pm2": item[7],
        "pm3": item[8]
    })

doc = DocxTemplate('template.docx')  # Загрузить шаблон (создать новый документ по шаблону)

context = {
    'tbl_contents': data_for_word
}

doc.render(context)  # Заполнить шаблон по данным из context

doc.save('table.docx')  # Сохранить в новый файл
```

Строки, состоящие только из пустых ячеек будут выводиться пустыми строками. Если они не нужны, нужно в цикле добавить такую проверку:

```
for item in data:
    # Проверяем, что хотя бы одно значение в строке не пустое
    # (даст истину, если в item хотя бы один элемент не пустая строка)
    if any(item):  
        data_for_word.append({
            "data": item[0],
            "time": item[1],
            "ph": item[2],
            "ph2": item[3],
            "fe": item[4],
            "pm": item[5],
            "co2": item[6],
            "pm2": item[7],
            "pm3": item[8]
        })
```

Comment: У меня в примере нет ui.doc.render, есть doc.render

Comment: Все работает! Только столбцы с данными чуть сдвинуты в право, это можно решить? Если нет то не особо кретично.

Comment: Скиньте скришот, не очень понятно что там происходит. Возможно просто вертикальные границы строк с данными сдвинуты относительно границ шапки таблицы. Можно попробовать те и другие границы в шаблоне подвигать, чтобы они к общему состоянию пришли

Comment: Прикрепил к вопросу.

Comment: @АндрейАлександров ну у вас в шаблоне точно так же смещено: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XFIt.png Поправьте в шаблоне, нормально будет и в готовом документе.

Comment: Извиняюсь за свою тупость. Спасибо за помощь. Вопрос можно считать закрытым.

Comment: @АндрейАлександров Если ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour