# Заполнение бланка в ворде python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ms-word, docxtpl

Только начал изучать python и хотел попробовать сделать заполнение определенной формы в таблице в ворде через него.

Пытался как-то сделать через docxtpl, но это работает немного не так, как я того хотел. Идея была в том, чтобы при запуске программы через input вводить значения для каждой ячейки в таблице, но как это сделать я не понимаю.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate

path = "D:\pycharm\shablon.docx"
doc = DocxTemplate(path)
context = {"name": "1", "numberdate": "1", "sum": "1", "object": "1",
           "fromwho": "1", "original": "1", "quantity": "1"}
doc.render(context)
doc.save("опись.docx")
```

Comment: Покажите ваш код, чтобы было от чего отталкиваться, чтобы помочь :)

Comment: @insolor понял, спасибо.

Comment: Если нужно всего одну строку заполнить, можно прямо внутри context вместо каждого "1" вставить input()

Comment: @insolor а если строчек много, то как это можно сделать?

Comment: А если строк много, то делать шаблон примерно как в этом ответе, и заполнять циклом: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1280467/1365

Comment: @insolor Перепробовал как только можно, но всё равно ничего не выходит. Заполняются все строчки одинаково.. Даже если присвоить каждой отдельной строчке разные имена и разные контексты, то всё равно выдает какие-то ошибки.

Comment: Я не телепат, не знаю как вы пробовали. Добавьте ваши попытки в вопрос. Я сегодня аналогичную задачу решал в другом вопросе, возможно такой код более понятен будет: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1322595/1365

Answer (score 0):

Если в вашей таблице всегда одна строчка, то действуйте также, как и сейчас указанно в вопросе.

Только у вас скорее всего данные не будут вставляться из-за того, что метки написаны так: `{{ sum }}`, а в коде вы пишите так `{{sum}}`. Пробелов в шаблоне Word между словом и кавычками быть не должно!